# How to de-dupe legend in faceted choropleth chart?

Tags: python, plotly, maps

I'm trying to create faceted maps by the column `rank` in my df. Each map will display the `product` for each `state`. I want the color of the product to be consistent across maps.
With the solution below I can achieve that, but the legend will show multiple entries for the same `product`, one for each `state`. How can I have the legend show only one entry per distinct product?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from random import randint

df = pd.DataFrame({'rank': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'product':['A','B','C','D','C','D','Z','X'],'state':['WA','OR','CA','ID','WA','OR','CA','ID']})

unique_hi = df['product'].unique()
color_discrete_map = {unique_hi[k]: '#%06X' % randint(0, 0xFFFFFF) for k in range(len(unique_hi))}

fig = px.choropleth(df, color='product', facet_col="rank",facet_col_wrap=2,
                    locations="state", #featureidkey="properties.district",
                    locationmode="USA-states",
                    projection="mercator",height=600,
                    color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map,
                    title='Regional products'
                   )
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":30,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the contents of the created map in `fig.data`, you will find the original name of the legend, which is collected and only the names of the non-duplicated.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from random import randint

df = pd.DataFrame({'rank': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'product':['A','B','C','D','C','D','Z','X'],'state':['WA','OR','CA','ID','WA','OR','CA','ID']})

unique_hi = df['product'].unique()
color_discrete_map = {unique_hi[k]: '#%06X' % randint(0, 0xFFFFFF) for k in range(len(unique_hi))}

fig = px.choropleth(df, color='product', facet_col="rank",facet_col_wrap=2,
                    locations="state", #featureidkey="properties.district",
                    locationmode="USA-states",
                    projection="mercator",height=600,
                    color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map,
                    title='Regional products'
                   )
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":30,"l":0,"b":0})

# update
names = set()
fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda trace:
        trace.update(showlegend=False)
        if (trace.name in names) else names.add(trace.name))

fig.show()
```

[image]

The way to add a product name as an annotation is not possible to specify it using map coordinates (I referred to [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/choropleth-map-with-annotations/24107) for the rationale), so adding the following code will make the annotation, but all products will need to be manually addressed. Upon further investigation, it [seems](https://community.plotly.com/t/annotations-on-plotly-choropleth/36219/8) that a combination of `go.choroplethmapbox()` and `go.scattergeo()` would do it. In this case, you will need to rewrite the code from scratch.

```
fig.add_annotation(
    x=0.2,
    xref='paper',
    y=0.85,
    yref='paper',
    text='A',
    showarrow=False,
    font=dict(
        color='yellow',
        size=14
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! Would you happen to know how to annotate the product on each state?